# Problems with setMaxResults() on MSSQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jpa

This is my method from my DAO class and its works

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Arquivo> listar() {
        try {
            Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Arquivo");
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

but when I put the setMaxResults() i get this SQL huge error saying something about a missing parameter on the statement

```
21:44:00,935 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-13) SQL Error: 102, SQLState: S0001
21:44:00,935 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-13) Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
21:44:00,938 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

21:44:00,938 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)

21:44:00,938 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)

21:44:00,938 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)

21:44:00,938 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.QueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.getResultList(QueryNonTxInvocationDetacher.java:58)

21:44:00,938 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at dao.ArquivoDao.listar(ArquivoDao.java:41)

21:44:00,938 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at service.ArquivoService.listar100(ArquivoService.java:19)

21:44:00,939 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at facade.ArquivoFacade.listaArquivos(ArquivoFacade.java:27)

21:44:00,939 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at facade.ArquivoFacade$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.listaArquivos(Unknown Source)

21:44:00,939 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

21:44:00,939 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

21:44:00,939 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

21:44:00,939 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

21:44:00,939 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)

21:44:00,940 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)

21:44:00,940 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)

21:44:00,940 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)

21:44:00,940 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)

21:44:00,940 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)

21:44:00,940 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)

21:44:00,940 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)

21:44:00,940 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)

21:44:00,941 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

21:44:00,941 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)

21:44:00,941 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

21:44:00,941 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

21:44:00,941 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

21:44:00,941 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

21:44:00,941 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

21:44:00,942 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

21:44:00,942 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

21:44:00,942 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

21:44:00,942 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

21:44:00,942 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)

21:44:00,942 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)

21:44:00,942 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)

21:44:00,943 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

21:44:00,943 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

21:44:00,943 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

21:44:00,943 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

21:44:00,943 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

21:44:00,943 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)

21:44:00,943 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

21:44:00,944 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)

21:44:00,944 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)

21:44:00,944 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

21:44:00,944 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

21:44:00,944 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

21:44:00,944 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

21:44:00,944 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

21:44:00,944 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

21:44:00,945 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

21:44:00,945 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)

21:44:00,945 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)

21:44:00,945 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)

21:44:00,945 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)

21:44:00,945 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)

21:44:00,945 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)

21:44:00,946 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

21:44:00,946 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

21:44:00,946 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

21:44:00,946 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

21:44:00,946 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)

21:44:00,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)

21:44:00,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)

21:44:00,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)

21:44:00,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)

21:44:00,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)

21:44:00,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)

21:44:00,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)

21:44:00,947 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)

21:44:00,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)

21:44:00,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)

21:44:00,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)

21:44:00,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)

21:44:00,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)

21:44:00,948 ERROR [stderr] (default task-13)   at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
```

It's a bug a knowing error or I messed up?

**update**
My perssitence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="monitoriabnbpu">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MSSQLARQCOM</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and my data source is on the wildfly 10.1

Comment: suppose you add a amount for `setMaxResults(int maxResults)`
          Set the maximum number of rows to retrieve.

Comment: I know @RajithPemabandu this so weird i put just 100

Comment: Add your persistence.xml and jdbc driver version

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.". I wonder what the SQL is then ...

Comment: I don't know what logger you're using, but see how to set `org.hibernate.SQL` to `debug` in it to log the query that Hibernate generates.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I used the wrong dialect

```
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```